# Memory leak after switching to @property declaration?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Why Im having a memory leak here:

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *info;
```

and then in my .m:

```
@synthesize info = _info;
```

and Im having one leak here:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.info = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:data];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And another leak here:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [self.info release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your leak stems from your property declaration and the way you assign it, when you declare a property as "retain" using the setter will retain the var for you, so doing

```
self.info = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:data];
```

Retains the var, and since alloc also retain the var you get a +2 retain count, you should either autorelease the object or assign it like

```
 _info = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:data];
```

also when you release a property do so by setting it to nil

```
self.info=nil
```

Comment: So every object I create with (nonatomic, retain) is not necessary to allocate it?

Comment: its not necesary to retain it... doing an NSDictionary alloc, allocates the object and retains it, if you do the [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:data], then this allocates the object and autoreleases it hence a retain count of 0, its equivalent to saying  [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:data] autorelease];

Comment: but Im creaqting a table in the exact same way, doing self.mainTable = [UITableView alloc]... and Im not having any leaks there!

Comment: are you auto releasing? How are you declaring the table property??

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor should use

```
self.info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:data];
```

Your dealloc should be simplified to

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.info = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: But what do these changes do?

Comment: You should read docs about objective c properties, and specifically about the "retain" attribute. Your code was correct for a property with the "assign" attribute.